# Undefined index after running function a few times

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

So I was trying to create my own Blackjack in javascript for learning purposes and even though the code is overall working, I came across a weird bug.

After some clicks on the `Deal` html button, which calls the function `deal()`, I will get either a `playerHand[i] undefined` or `dealerHand[i]` undefined error on line 114 or 118, respectively, of the code posted below.

I noticed this also happened if I clicked the button very fast for whatever reason.
I suspected it had something to do with memory optimization so I used the `delete` command to reset those arrays between game turns, but the error persists.

So, why do my arrays break after some use?

Thanks.

JS:

```
var deck = [];

var dealerHand = [];
var playerHand = [];

var dscore = 0;
var pscore = 0;

var turn = 0;

function Card(suit, src) {
    this.src = src;
    this.suit = getSuit(suit);
    this.value = getValue(src);
};

function getSuit(suit) {
    if (suit == 1) return "Clubs";
    if (suit == 2) return "Diamonds";
    if (suit == 3) return "Hearts";
    if (suit == 4) return "Spades";
};

function getValue(src) {
    if (src == 1) return 11;
    if (src < 10) return src;
    else return 10;
};

function createDeck() {
    for (i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        for(j=1; j<=13; j++) {
            var card = new Card(i, j);
            deck.push(card);
        };
    };
};

function getCard() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    deck.splice(rand,1);
    return deck[rand];
};

function deal() {
    if(turn == 0) {
        dealerHand.push(getCard());
        playerHand.push(getCard());
    };
    dealerHand.push(getCard());
    playerHand.push(getCard());
};

function stand() {
    dealerHand.push(getCard());
};

function clearBoard () {
    $('#player').html("");
    $('#dealer').html("");
};

function resetDeck () {
    delete deck;
    deck = [];
};

function resetHands () {
    delete dealerHand;
    delete playerHand;
    dealerHand = [];
    playerHand = [];
};

function resetScore () {
    pscore = 0;
    dscore = 0;
};

function isAce (arr) {
    for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].src == 1) return true;
        else return false;
    };
}

function updateScore() {
    resetScore();

    if (playerHand.length > 0 && dealerHand.length > 0) {
        for(i=0; i<playerHand.length; i++) {
            pscore += playerHand[i].value;
        };

        for(i=0; i<dealerHand.length; i++) {
            dscore += dealerHand[i].value;
        };

        //Regra do Às
        if(pscore > 21 && isAce(playerHand)) {
            pscore -= 10;
        };

        if(dscore > 21 && isAce(dealerHand)) {
            dscore -= 10;
        };
    } else {
        pscore = 0;
        dscore = 0;
    };
};

function showScore () {
    $('#pscore').html("<p>Player Score: " + pscore + "</p>");
    $('#dscore').html("<p>Dealer Score: " + dscore + "</p>");
};

function showCards () {
    for(i=0; i<playerHand.length; i++) {
        var div = $("<div>");
        var img = $("<img>");
        img.attr('src', 'img/cards/' + playerHand[i].suit + '/' + playerHand[i].src + '.png');
        div.append(img);

        $('#player').append(div);
    };

    for(i=0; i<dealerHand.length; i++) {
        var div = $("<div>");
        var img = $("<img>");
        img.attr('src', 'img/cards/' + dealerHand[i].suit + '/' + dealerHand[i].src + '.png');
        div.append(img);

        $('#dealer').append(div);
    };
};

function cleanUp () {
    if (pscore == 21) {
        alert("Blackjack!");
        newGame();
    };

    if (pscore > 21) {
        alert("Bust!");
        newGame();
    };

    if (dscore == 21) {
        alert("You lost!");
        newGame();
    };

    if (dscore > 21) {
        alert("You won!");
        newGame();
    };
};

function newGame () {
    turn = 0;
    clearBoard();
    resetHands();
    resetScore();
    showScore();
    resetDeck();
    createDeck();
};

function gameTurn () {
    clearBoard();
    updateScore();
    showCards();
    showScore();
    cleanUp();
    turn++;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    newGame();

    $('#deal').on('click', function(){
        deal();
        gameTurn();
    });

    $('#stand').on('click', function(){
        stand();
        gameTurn();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(../img/greenbg.png);
}

.holder { 
    width:800px;
    margin:auto;
}

.clearfix { 
    clear:both;
}

#pscore, #dscore {
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
}

.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
}

div img {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

div button {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <div class="holder clearfix">
            <div id="dscore"><p>Dealer Score: 0</p>
            </div>
            <div id="dealer" class="container">
            </div>
            <div id="pscore"><p>Player Score: 0</p>
            </div>
            <div id="player" class="container">
            </div>
            <div class="">
                <button id="deal">Deal</button>
                <button id="stand">Stand</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please make a jsfiddle or something with this in it.

Comment: The delete function removes properties from objects, don't use it for something else.

Comment: @Nit Will remove it, thank you.

Comment: @tkone I intended to, but because this code works with a set of .png cards it would be pointless because you wouldn't see the javascript actually doing anything.

Comment: Your IsAce function only tests if the first card in the hand is an ace, since either condition in the if returns immediately after testing the first one.  Also, it looks like updateScore will not handle 2 aces in your hand.

Comment: @user1689571 good spot on the `isAce` function, but see the p.s. in my answer for a more modern idiomatic solution.

Comment: @user1689571 You do have a point. Weird I did not notice that before while playing. I will probably just rewrite the whole isAce thing as suggested by Alnitak. Will also have to rewrite the updateScore apprently. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I had to come up with something, Alnitak, since you beat me to the splice bug...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem in this function, which may be to blame:

```
function getCard() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*deck.length);
    deck.splice(rand,1);
    return deck[rand];
};
```

As written, it's removing a card, and then returning the card that now has that position in the deck.  If `rand` was the last element in the array then there is no longer a card in that position, so it'll return `undefined`.

You should be returning the value of the removed card itself, part of the result of the `splice` call:

```
function getCard() {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * deck.length);
    var pick = deck.splice(rand, 1);
    return pick[0];
};
```

---

p.s. it's worth learning modern ES5 utility functions for arrays.  For example, your `isAce` function could be rewritten thus, avoiding the bug where you always `return` after testing the first element:

```
function isAce(arr) {
    return arr.some(function(n) {
        return n === 1;
    });
};
```

or, more cleanly:

```
function isAce(card) {
    return card === 1;        // test a single card
};

function holdsAce(hand) {
    return hand.some(isAce);  // test an array (or hand) of cards
};
```

Comment: This most likely the cause of the problem. After x number of tries I would definitely get an undefined value from the deck array. Thanks a lot!